# Role of IMockProviderService.VerifyInteractions in Pact?

Tags: pact, pact-broker

What is the Role of IMockProviderService.VerifyInteractions in Pact?
and what is the best practice to use it?

Answer (score 0):

`VerifyInteractions` verifies that the expected requests that were set up on the mock service have actually been made by the code under test.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elobrate more? How does VerifyInteractions verify that request has been made by code under test?